# Vmware workstation bridge network: can only connect with the host

Tags: vmware-workstation, bridge

I have an windows 7 host with VMWare Workstation 7.0.0 and a Debian 6 guest.
If I use a NAT network interface it works but I need the guest with a IP address from my public network.

If I use a bridge nic the guest can ping the host but can't ping any other machine[inside or outside the LAN].

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you call it a LAN if it gets a public IP address? Can you share a little more of the design with us? What kind of ISP (cable/dsl/private circuit). Do you have a router? In many cases an ISP will only talk to one MAC address at a time.

Comment: You're right, technically its a LAN but it assigns Public IPs, I have a reserved segment and a DHCP in it. 
The guest can obtain an IP from dhcp but it has no connectivity except with the host.

Comment: Solved, it was a nested vmware virtualization problem, (workstation over esx) and a vswitch wich was not in promiscuous mode. <b>This question can be closed</b>. Thanks to @SpacemanSpiff.

Comment: that actually makes complete sense, glad you got it fixed, you should accept the answer.